# Can this be considered overfitting?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, transfer-learning

I have 4 classes, each with 1350 images. The validation set has 20% of the total images (it is generated automatically). The training model uses MobilenetV2 network:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

The model is created:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))
])
```

The model is trained through 20 epochs and then fine tunning is done in 15 epochs. The result is as follows:

[Image of the model trained before fine tunning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aWCi.png)

[Image of the model trained after 15 epochs and fine tunning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eBJH.png)

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult to tell without the numeric values of validation loss but I would say the results before fine tuning are slightly over fitting and for after fine tuning less over fitting. A couple of additional things you could do. One is try using an adjustable learning rate using the callback tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau. Set it up to monitor validation loss. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau) I set factor=.5 and patience=1. Second replace the Flatten layer with tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D and see if it improves the validation loss.

Comment: After I add tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D the values are as follows: `Epoch 20/20
68/68 [==============================] - 26s 377ms/step - loss: 0.1982 - accuracy: 0.9833 - val_loss: 0.7288 - val_accuracy: 0.7926`

Comment: try adding keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 ) before the final dense layer and see if that helps.

Comment: I have this: `Epoch 20/20
68/68 [==============================] - 26s 377ms/step - loss: 0.1422 - accuracy: 0.9817 - val_loss: 1.0297 - val_accuracy: 0.7685`